# spring-cloud-starter-oauth2 and spring-boot-starter-webflux no server on start

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-webflux

I have a simple spring application that use

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

My other dependencies are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I'have created a dummy controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @GetMapping("/")
    String get(){
        return "HELLO";
    }
}
```

When I start the app I have strange error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$Enable WebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
```

It's seems that I have a conflict with spring-webmvc and webflux.
I want to be reactive and webmvc do not play well with spring reactive based on what I've read, So I've exclude spring-web-starter, but then I have...

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start reactive web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'httpHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/HttpHandlerAutoConfiguration$AnnotationConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.server.reactive.HttpHandler]: Factory method 'httpHandler' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/WebFluxAnnotationAutoConfiguration$EnableWebFluxConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/WebFluxAnnotationAutoConfiguration$EnableWebFluxConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
```

What is needed to make spring oauth2 works with spring-webflux ?

for info I am using snapshot for everything.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported at the moment (neither is the reactive bits of Spring Security).

Comment: Hi Brian, your comment is a year old, is it still not supported? Thanks.